# CakePHP Assigning Records to Users: A Re-Usable Approach

Tags: database-design, cakephp, permissions, filtering

I am having a bit of difficulty in trying to come-up with a good solution for assigning any record in my app to a User or Group and to then filter that model according to these assignments.

I came up with the following Assignment-model:

```
Assignment
  -id
  -assignedto_key
  -assignedto_model (either User or Group [hasMany/belongsTo is between User and Group])
  -foreign_key
  -foreign_model
```

So far so good. Now I want to be able to assign any record in my app to a whole group or a load of individual users.

For instance:

```
Assignment
  -id = 1 (I'm actually using UUIDs)
  -assignedto_key = 1
  -assignedto_model = User (so this would be assigned to User.id = 1)
  -foreign_key = 1
  -foreign_model = Painting

Assignment
  -id = 2 (I'm actually using UUIDs)
  -assignedto_key = 1
  -assignedto_model = Group (so this would be assigned to any User with group_id = 1)
  -foreign_key = 1
  -foreign_model = Painting

Therefore: User 1 can now access the Painting 1. Furthermore, ANY user with group_id = 1 can also access Painting 1.
```

So far so good. I am having no trouble to create a the logic that enables administrators to go into a record (say, a Painting) and to select the groups/users that should be able to see this.

However, where I am lost is when I want to filter the data:

Basically, I need to be able to only return the records to users, which they have access to.

Currently, I am thinking of realising this as a behaviour, which I would attach to all the models that are "Assignable".

```
public function beforeFind(Model &$model, $query)
{
   // Let's imagine that $model is of type Painting
   // I can only think of the following solution:

   $Assignment = ClassRegistry::init('Assignment');
   $assignedIDs = $Assignment->find('all', array('fields'=> array('id'), 'conditions' => array(
       'Assignment.foreign_model' => $model->alias,
       'or' => array(
                  array('Assignment.foreign_model' => 'User', 'Assignment.foreign_key' => AuthComponent::user('id')),
                  array('Assignment.foreign_model' => 'Group', 'Assignment.foreign_key' => AuthComponent::user('group_id'))
               )
   )));

   $ids = Set::extract('{n}.' . $this->alias . '.id', $assignedIDs);

   $query['conditions'][] = array($this->alias . '.id' => $ids);
}
```

The above would get all assignments within the current model and only query within those. But this seems totally inefficient to me.

Would anyone have any pointers as to how I could realise such a functionality?

Many thanks in advance and I look forward to your replies.

**Edit:** Just as a side-note - I don't think that I am looking for ACL in this case since I wish to only return filtered results - but I may well be wrongly assuming that ACL is not the right option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing here is a 'Polymorphic Relationship'. Pure DB'er frown on them as the relation is encoded in the data, not the schema. The rest of us use 'em because they work ;-)

Have you seen: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/AD7six/2008/03/13/polymorphic-behavior (it's a 1.3 behavior, but portable to 2.x). It handles a lot of the leg work of dealing with polymorphic tables.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Polymorphic - it definitely is a great way for implementing such dynamic relationships. However, in this case, I believe it would rather be a "double polymorphic" relationship? Or I may also not understand entirely - apologies if that is the case!

The problem is that the table should belongTo (either) User or Group AND belongTo any other model. 

In any case, many thanks for pointing that one out! :-)